# Can one Ethernet cable supply internet and an SSH connection?

Tags: ssh, putty, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to connect a Raspberry Pi to my laptop such that I can control it over SSH (PuTTY). However, the Pi itself needs internet. Is it possible to supply by the SSH commands and the internet connection through one Ethernet cable?

Comment: Hook the Pi to Internet and then log into it. If you want the Pi to get Internet from the laptop you need to enable Internet Connection Sharing.

Comment: I tried this but it seemed to cut off the SSH

Comment: If the Ethernet cable connects the Pi to your router, it should have internet and be available for SSH on the local network. What is your setup?

Comment: How does your _laptop_ get internet access?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the same network you can plug it into Ethernet and connect wirelessly using SSH.